# How to read the status of the Power-LED on Raspberry Pi 3 with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

How to read the status of the Power-LED (or the rainbow square - if you like that better) on Raspberry Pi 3 to detect an low-voltage-condition in a python script? Since the wiring of the Power-LED has changed since Raspberry Pi 2, it seems that GPIO 35 cannot longer be used for that purpose.

---

**Update:**

Since it seems to be non-trivial to detect a low-power-condition in code on Raspberry Pi 3, i solved it with a quick hardware hack. I soldered a wire between the Output of the APX803 (the power-monitoring device used on Pi 3) and GPIO26 and that way I can simply read GPIO26 to get the power status. Works like a charm.

Comment: also try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good point. I was not aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because of Pi3's BT/wifi support Power LED is controlled directly from the GPU through a GPIO expander.

I believe that there's no way to do what you want

Comment: I think there must be a way since Raspbian shows the rainbow square if voltage is low and therefore, it must get to that information in any way.

Comment: The rainbow square is drawn by the GPU, not by Raspbian

Comment: Ah, ok - makes sense since it's visible before Raspbian is up and running :). So there may be a way to query the GPU?!

Comment: I don't know this, sorry

Comment: @theBugger what you're saying is that the power LED cannot be accessible using  any of the 40 GPIO ?

Comment: Exactly, not since Pi 3 board. If you can afford an hardware mod, solder a wire to bring the LED signal on a GPIO port

Comment: You can read the power LED status - check out the comment https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332#issuecomment-274338891

Answer (score 0):

I have dig into the topic. Found a very good [discussion](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332). In RPi 3 control of power LED from GPIO has been removed as OP mentioned.

The probable reason:

> The power LED is different on Pi3. It is controlled from GPU through a
>   GPIO expander which is configured as an input. It may not be possible
>   to drive it from the arm (certainly it is not currently). **Pi3's
>   BT/wifi support required a number of additional GPIOs compared to Pi2**.
>   So, the ACT and PWR leds had to move to make that possible.

Also:

> Since the B+ the functionality of PWR LED has doubled, power indicator
>   and as well as an under-voltage indicator. Since GPIOs are in short
>   supply, as well as being an indicator it is also the under-voltage
>   detector - there is some external circuitry that can detect the GPIO
>   direction so that it is either an input with an automatic LED or an
>   output. This circuitry is only present on the red LED. **The ability to
>   change the "PWR" LED pin to an output, bypasses the under-voltage detection, which is permitted but
>   not recommended**.
>
> These GPIOs may never be available as fully
>   featured GPIOs because they are too slow to use in many circumstances.
>   There is a simple GPIO driver that can efficiently control the ACT
>   LED, but more effort is needed to make it work with the PWR LED and
>   change its direction to an output. **This is something we may address,
>   but it isn't high on the list of priorities at the moment**.

---

**The possible wayout**: Didn't find any way of using Python to access GPU, but found some discussions regarding accessing GPU configuration - sharing it as looking into it could be helpful for you in replicating an equivalent functionality in Python.

> There is also the mailbox service that would allow userspace to **fiddle
>   with the outputs on the expander**, but not set direction - see
>   https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=109137&start=100#p990152
>   and https://github.com/6by9/rpi3-gpiovirtbuf

[Also](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332#issuecomment-231744888):

> For the complete list of GPIO allocations, look at the dt-blob.dts
>   that configures the GPU side -
>   https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/extra/dt-blob.dts#L1175
>   Documentation is at
>   https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/pin-configuration.md

If I get something helpful 'll post it as update 2.

Comment: This is not valid for Pi 3 boards

Comment: This question is about reading the led state, not setting it.

Comment: My bad, I haven't tried it myself, I'll get my RPi 3 up running within few days. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You can post your issue here, as it's still open - https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332 way to read status of Power LED